# How can i list all hierarcheis of modules/submodules in verilog/system verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, iverilog

I want to view a list of all modules/sub-modules/instances in verilog/system-verilog compilation; is that possible? I know i can do a *%m* in *$display* and it will show the hierarchy of that particular instance.  I want to get a similar list but for all the modules and instance which I can use for later post-processing. Would this information be EDA tool dependent?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you can create a VPI application to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most simulation tools provide commands to this either with some kind of report, or creating a simple Tcl script.

You can also do this using SystemVerilog's VPI or DPI/VPI combination so it won't be tool dependent. See my 2016 DVCon paper: [Introspection into SystemVerilog without Turning It Inside Out](https://www.mentor.com/products/fv/resources/overview/introspection-into-systemverilog-without-turning-it-inside-out-08587fce-0e73-400f-b2f6-0bbd6a2fe746)

Comment: do you know the command for questa/modelsim?
now that I saw this question... I need to know.

Comment: `find instances`